# RoR - Rending links in posts

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, blogs

I'm building a website in Rails after not having used it in a very long time, a small part of the site will be a simple blog structure for news. I started with the basic post/view structure that rails generates, albeit altered a bit to make it a little more specialized. Everything is working fine except one error that I keep running into, within posts I need to be able to create links and images (duh) but just throwing html into my posts means they wont render and the html tags just show up (e.g.  stuff etc) and the same goes for ruby tags (which I assumed would be so since its post-parse when it is being posted. I assumed this was because rails was sanitizing the posts when they were being created somewhere along the line but couldn't find any code that was doing this... I'm sure someone has run into this problem before but I can't find anything about this anywhere, any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to use the raw method? <%= raw @post.body %>

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to rails escaping HTML tags for safty. You could use raw method to overcome this

```
Ex: <a htef='http://google.com'>google </a>

<%= raw("<a htef='http://google.com'>google </a>")%> #will render the hyperlink
```

HTH